# Show source code for selected class name in editor in IntelliJ 2018.1

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Through Maven, I have the source code and JavaDoc both downloaded for libraries used by my code.

I want to select a class name called in my code in the IntelliJ code editor, and then ask IntelliJ to show me the source code for that particular class.

Bonus: Show the JavaDoc for that class.

I thought `F1` key would do this, but no so.

If a keyboard shortcut is required, please indicate the macOS version as well as the PC version if known.

Comment: Ubuntu 18 - `ctrl + click`

Comment: @Justice That led me to `Command`+`click` for macOS. Thanks! Holding down that key causes class names to become web-style links as the mouse passes over.

Comment: Sweet! Glad I could help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Hold `Command` key, hover mouse, and click

On a Mac, hold down the `Command` key. Notice as you move the mouse pointer, the class names change to blue underscored text like an old-school web page link. Click that retro-link while holding down Command.

I am guessing, per comment by Justice, that on a PC you would hold down `Control` key while hovering/clicking.

No need to select the class name.

### Before, no keys pressed

[image]

### After, pressing `Command` while hovering mouse pointer

[image]

Click the apparent link to open the local copy of class source code.

This approach worked on IntelliJ 2018.1 on macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> will open a text box where you can search for the class by name, and then open it, regardless of whether it's a class that's part of your project's sources or a library you use. If you have the library's source downloaded, IntelliJ IDEA will show you that instead of the decompiled binary of the class.

Answer (score 0):

COMMAND+B is used to show source code after selecting the class or interface  for IntelliJ Users.